# Hide AceEditor on resize past a minimum height

Tags: ace-editor

I have Ace Editor in a draggable group and it looks like there is a min height applied to it.

Is there a way to set this min height or better yet is there a way to hide the ace editor when the height is less than the min height?

Comment: ace doesn't have a min-height by itself, this must be something set by your code.

Comment: OK I'll look into it.

Comment: On further research it was an unrelated issue that made it appear it had a min height.